# continue execution after running some .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

example buil.bat script

```
start /B webdev.webserver.exe /port:3234 /path:C:\projects\src\XYZWeb /VPATH:/XYZWeb
```

when program run this script also execution stop. How to continue execution after running this script. Problem is that build.bat never end and you must manually close it.

i look here http://ss64.com/nt/start.html but no command to conitinue executing while webdev.webserver is running.

Comment: are you saying that the calling window never returns when calling this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me when I added the window title (as the page you link suggested), and the full path to the exe in quotes.

```
start "webserver" /B "<fullpath>\webdev.webserver.exe" /port:3234 /path:C:\projects\src\XYZWeb /VPATH:/XYZWeb
```